# Trying to export a list with "stsadm -o export" throws "Invalid high surrogate character"

Tags: 2013, powershell, export

I am trying to export a Sharepoint list with forlders with the next commands:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity https://webapurl.com -ItemUrl /Lists/ListName/ -Path D:/Folder/file.cmp -IncludeVersions All
or
stsadm -o export -url https://webapurl.com/Lists/ListName/ -filename D:/Folder/file.cmp
```

In both cases, when trying to export certain items (always the same items), throws this:

> FatalError: Invalid high surrogate character (0xDF8A). A high
>   surrogate character must have a value from range (0xD800 - 0xDBFF).

This happens with about 5% or 10% from all items in the library (there are about 40.000 including folders).

Any idea or workaround to export and import them in another web application maintaining dates and authors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default command not working like that (only sites, subsites), if you need export\import library or list try it another solution: **lapointe.sharepoint.stsadm.commands.wsp**
The most important thing is that "Created By" and "Created" are saved in the original form.

```
stsadm -o gl-exportlist -url "http://sharepoint/sites/TIS/Lists/veda/overview.aspx" -filename "C:\Folder\TIS.cmp" -includeusersecurity
stsadm -o gl-importlist -url "http://sharepoint/sites/TIS" -filename "C:\Folder\TIS.cmp" -includeusersecurity
```

[Lapointe.SharePoint.STSADM.Commands](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/)